# Is there a way to detect current javascript runs in async or sync?

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript file that will load external javascript or css files into current page and that javascript may be using `document.write('<script>...')` or `document.createElement('script')` for load external files.

My quesition is if that javascript uses async loaded I will not able via `document.write('<script>...')` to load files, and the console of browser will give back a message say "Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.".

That's look like must using `document.createElement('script')` for load external, but I don't know how to detect current javascript runs in async or sync? Is there a way to do this? can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: I would advise not using any script which uses `document.write`, as it's probably not any good.

Comment: `I have a javascript file that will load external javascript ... that javascript may be using document.write('...')` - you'll have nothing but pain and suffering

Comment: I know using document.write() not a good idea, but I need to use document.write(...) have a required reason. because sometime some javascripts have to blocking the DOM parsing. e.g. the html5shiv.js (a patch for not supported html5 of browsers).

Comment: May be you want to make sure the contents of the current script tag are loaded before executing your logic. if so then you can attach an event handler for readystatechange event : var script = document.createElement(''script); script.onreadystatechange = function() { }